# Unclear Python Syntax/Errors

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I'm getting an error:

> NameError: name 'barley_amount' is not defined

Here's my code:

```
    from ctypes import *

class barley_amount(Union):
    _fields_ = [
                ("barley_long", c_long),
                ("barley_int", c_int),
                ("barley_char", c_char)
                ]
    value = raw_input("Enter the amount of Barley to put into the beer vat: ")
    my_barley = barley_amount(int(value))
    print "Barley amount as a long: %ld" % my_barley.barley_long 
    print "Barley amount as an int: %d" % my_barley.barley_long
    print "Barley amount as a char: %s" % my_barley.barley_char`from ctypes import *

    my_barley = barley_amount(int(value))
    print "Barley amount as a long: %ld" % my_barley.barley_long 
    print "Barley amount as an int: %d" % my_barley.barley_long
    print "Barley amount as a char: %s" % my_barley.barley_char
```

I took this example from a book, and even copy posted it when I kept getting errors.  I'm using PyDev with eclipse.  Anyone have any idea on what's going on here?  Oh, Python 2.7.1 I'm using, too.

Comment: utdmr's answer explains how to fix the problem, but the reason for the specific error message is that while the body of the class definition is being executed, `barley_amount` has not yet been defined.

Answer (score 5):

Indentation matters in Python. And the last part(starts with `from ctypes at line 13) is wrong. The true code is:

```
from ctypes import *

class barley_amount(Union):
    _fields_ = [
                ("barley_long", c_long),
                ("barley_int", c_int),
                ("barley_char", c_char)
                ]

value = raw_input("Enter the amount of Barley to put into the beer vat: ")
my_barley = barley_amount(int(value))
print "Barley amount as a long: %ld" % my_barley.barley_long 
print "Barley amount as an int: %d" % my_barley.barley_long
print "Barley amount as a char: %s" % my_barley.barley_char
```

Answer (score 0):

i spent a long time banging my head on this as well, you do not have a blank line after the end of the union "]"

add a space before value and it should work find other then the already mentioned random ctypes import at the end again.